# Disable Spring logging on Payara web server for certain packages

Tags: java, spring, payara

I am deploying a Java 11 Spring Application (version 4.3.10) on Payara 5.2020.6. The problem is Spring logs all invocation to REST endpoints, causing the Payara logs to occupy a lot of disk space, which runs out very quickly.
The format of a message is something like this:

```
[2021-04-05T12:53:08.794+0300] [Payara 5.2020.6] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=90 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1617616388794] [levelValue: 800] [[
  3294283 [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Checking match of request : '/rest/somepath/v1/someendpoint'; against '/rest/someotherpath/v1/someotherendpoint'
]]
```

I have tried to filter out this package from the Payara web console administration but the problem is the package name is included in the message itself (together with the log level) and Payara offers no option on filtering out based on this criterion (only the possibility to search upon a string contained within the message, in the LogViewer).
Does anyone know how can I configure Payara so that certain messages are being excluded from the Payara logs?